# Detect if elements are removed jQuery

Tags: jquery

Ok,

so I have:

```
<ul>
<li>hello</li>
<li>bye</li>
</ul>
```

Then:

```
$('li').click(function(){
$(this).remove();
})
```

But then i have:

```
if($('ul li').length == 0){
        $('ul').append('<li>You haven\'t favourited anything. Get to it!</li>');    
    }
```

But it doesn't work!

Comment: where is that if statement located?  i think we need to see the rest of your code :)

Comment: The if statement is below the remove() function

Comment: No, separate, i take it might need to go in the click handler

Comment: what exactly is not working? appears to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pcY54/

Comment: yes, that would make sense.  if you want it to check and add the new one after they have clicked on one.

Comment: @themerlinproject Your jsfiddle does not update the list when no `<li>` elements exist.

Comment: does he want the li to update only when elements are clicked away, or if the list loads with nothing? If the latter than putting it inside click() won't accomplish everything. We are missing a key piece of information here: what is the end result he is trying to accomplish?

Comment: this will accomplish both: http://jsfiddle.net/pcY54/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    if($('ul li').length == 0){
      $('ul').append('<li>You haven\'t favourited anything. Get to it!</li>');    
    }
});
```

If you put that if statement outside of the call back, it tests for "no li elements" when the page loads, basically. You want it to test for "no li elements" after you have removed one, so the right place to do this is after you remove one. :)

Answer (score 0):

This will check for list items when the document loads AND if a user clicks away all the list items:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

checklist();

$('li').click(function(){
 $(this).remove();
 checklist();
})

function checklist() {
    if($('ul li').length == 0) $('ul').append('<li>You haven\'t favourited anything. Get to it!</li>'); } 

 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pcY54/4/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to just put that `if` block inside the `click` handler, so it will re-evaluate after removing an element and then add that message. As it is it just runs once on page load, and never again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine, here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pcY54/2/

```
//use jQuery 1.7's `.on()` function to delegate an event handler to the click event
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){

    //remove the clicked `<li>` element
    $(this).remove();

    //check to see if there are any `<li>` elements left
    if($('ul li').length == 0){

        //if there are no `<li>` elements then add one with a default message
        $('ul').append('<li>You haven\'t favourited anything. Get to it!</li>');    
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if any li's are present after you have clicked on them:

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).remove();
    checkLiLength()
})

function checkLiLength(){
    if($('ul li').length == 0){
        $('ul').append('<li>You haven\'t favourited anything. Get to it!</li>');    
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pcY54/1/

Answer (score 0):

I looked into my crystal ball and this seems to appear to be a dynamic list where you can append elements and then remove them and append again and so on?

If so, you cannot use bind but need to use event delegation in a higher level element like so:

```
$('ul').delegate("li", "click", function(){
$(this).remove();

    if($('ul li').length <= 0){
        $('ul').append('<li>You haven\'t favourited anything. Get to it!</li>');    
    }
})
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pcY54/3/